# What is the use of defining a Global Descriptor Table?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, kernel, gdt

I read a tutorial on GDT (Global Descriptor Table) which defines GDT as " the one that defines base access privileges for certain parts of memory ". That means GDT is used for memory protection.

Does it perform any other tasks other than the above?

Is it a must to implement a GDT in an Operating System?

In short it would be better if anyone could elaborate on GDT in a way easy to understand.

Thanks

Comment: sounds like you got it.  defines base access priviledges for memory, wouldnt be that useful if anyone other than the operating system had access to it.

Comment: It is a must to have a GDT to get into protected mode (you can't get into protected mode without one). There are tutorials on [ODSdev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/GDT_Tutorial) about the GDT.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

All the images have been taken from [Intel Manual 3A, §5.1](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.html).
For further details the OP should read that manual, here I will expose just some concepts simplified for the sake of brevity and to avoid a link-only answer.

---

As the name suggests the *Global Descriptor Table* is an array of **descriptors** available to specify and define system wide resources (hence **describe** those resources).

More often than not the resource is an area of **continuous memory** but there are other kinds of very important resources too.

The taxonomy of the descriptors is

```
Descriptors
    Non system descriptors

        Code segment descriptor
        Data segment descriptor
        Stack segment descriptor (Alias of the previous)

    System descriptors

        System segment descriptors

            LDT segment descriptor
            TSS segment descriptor

        Gate descriptors
            Call gate descriptor
            Interrupt gate descriptor
            Trap gate descriptor
            Task gate descriptor
```

Other than the *GDT* there is another table, the **Local Descriptor Table** that describes resources made available by the OS to specific contexts only.

A descriptor is identified by its table (either *GDT* or *LDT*) and its position on the table, its *index*.

Such index is written into specific registers, called **selector registers** (previously known as *segment registers*).
Every instruction that accesses memory implicitly or explicitly uses one of the selectors.

```
xor eax, eax     ;eax is zero
xor esp, esp     ;esp is zero
xor ebx, ebx     ;ebx is zero

mov ecx, DWORD [eax]      ;Use DS selector (implicit)
mov ecx, DWORD [esp]      ;Use SS selector (implicit)
mov ecx, DWORD [fs:ebx]   ;Use FS selector (explicit)
```

All these instructions read the **logical address** 0 but the CPU uses the descriptor to compute a new address, called **linear address** and perform security checks.
So those three instructions may end up reading totally different addresses.

Each selector also specifies the privilege which should be used when carrying out an operation.
The `cs` selector is special because it cannot be longer changed (it has been a while actually) with a `mov` but only with a branch instruction (`jmp`, `ret`, `call`, ...).
Its purpose is not only to be used when fetching code, it also holds the code privilege level.
This privilege level is used by the CPU to check if a resource can be accessed (with the requested privilege), checks are not always trivial.

As you will see, every descriptor has a *DPL* field to set its privilege level.
So they are a form of **protection**.

### Non system descriptors

Non system descriptors are used to define regions of memory intended to store code or data along with their attributes.

[image: Non system descriptors]

As you can see, the purpose of this kind of descriptors is to designate an area of memory and attach some attributes to it.
In particular the base address, the limit (size), the privilege needed to access it (the *DPL* field, checks are actually more involved than this), the size of the code (code only), if read/write is allowed and so on.

Long mode (64 bits) changed how the attributes are interpreted, beware of that.

### System descriptors

System descriptors are used by the OS to control user mode programs.

## System segment descriptors

These descriptors define the memory area used for storing the *LDT* and another structure called **Task State Segment** (a mechanism Intel provided for easing task switching).
There can be more than one of these structures on the system, the selected ones are indicated by the *ldtr* (LDT register) and *tsr* (TS register) registers.

[image: System segment descriptors]

## Gate descriptors

These are used to transfer control to other (more or less privileged) code.

**Call gates**

[image: Call gate]

If you look at the picture you can see that a *call gate* is essentially a meta descriptor, it specifies a selector and an offset into the area designated by that descriptor along with privileges.
It is used to pass control to privileged routines.

```
call fs:0badbabeh
```

Assuming `fs` holds a gate's index, the CPU won't use the immediate address *0badbabeh* at all, it will instead use the information on the gate itself.

**Interrupt and Trap gates**

These are used with interrupts, the difference between the two is that the former clear the *if* flag, the latter doesn't.

They are very similar to call gates.

[image: Interrupt and Trap gates]

These descriptors are actually placed into another table, the **Interrupt Descriptor Table** usually.
This other table is not indexed with selectors but with interrupt numbers.
If I recall correctly they can also be placed in the *GDT*/*LDT* and used like other gates.

A *Task gate* can be used to perform a task switch.

**Task gates**

[image: Task gates]

These are like the call gates but transfer control to a new task (task switching).

Some resources are not simple memory area, they can be **gates**

Answer (score -5):

Let me give you two answers to your question:

Answer #1: In 64-bit Intel, the Global Descriptor Table serves no useful purpose.

Answer #2: In 16-Bit Intel, the Global Descriptor Table contained the descriptors for objects shared by all processes on the system. The Local Descriptor Tables did the same for those used by individual process. There could be multiple LDTs (one per process) but only one GDT shared by all processes (although in theory one could change the GDT for different processes).

In 32-Bit Intel, the GDT and LDTs were needed for running legacy 16-bit code in 32-bit systems.

Unless you have some need for dealing with 16-bit applications, learning about GDTs and LDTs is as useful as learning how to operate a punch card machine.

Comment: The GDT is still necessary in 64-bit operating systems. You need to create at least one selector for 64-bit code. Most 64-bit operating systems would create at least six, one each for 64-bit ring 0 code, 64-bit ring 3 code, 64-bit TSS, 32-bit ring 3 code, 32-bit ring 3 data, and 32-bit ring 3 thread local storage. A 32-bit operating system needs at least two selectors, and similarly most will have at least six selectors defined in the GDT,

Comment: There is not such thing as GDT in "16-Bit Intel" (did you mean real mode?). In protected mode ("32-Bit Intel") the GDT and IDT are actually mandatory, they **are** the protection (beside page level protection). The whole answer is wrong, but the last paragraph is astonishingly wrong.

Comment: @MargaretBloom : The GDT is mandatory but the IDT is optional. Although a kernel without an IDT and interrupts will be less than useful ;-)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, you are right. I often found myself switching into PM without enabling the interrupts just to avoid the IDT handling altogether :)