# What is the relation between Selector and GDT in PM?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, selector, gdt

I went through many of the tutorials available on the Net about the Global Descriptor Table. But I couldn't find a site which explains all the fields in the 64-bit descriptor in detail. Moreover I was stuck with the selector concept in the GDT. I know a selector has an Index, TI for whether GDT or LDT fields. 
 In simple, What is the relation that relates a selector with the GDT?
 If possible please explain in detail.

Thank you..

Comment: A selector is an index into the GDT or LDT. The TI bit tells you which.

Comment: Did you look in Intel's official docs?  (links in [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) Intel documents pretty much everything in full detail with diagrams in their PDFs.  Also, did you check http://wiki.osdev.org/GDT points you to the right page of Intel's docs for the long-mode GDT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming Protected Mode.

The 16 bits registers `cs`, `ds`, `es`, `ss`, `fs` and `gs` are called *Selector registers*, each contains a value called *Selector*.

A *selector* is made up of three fields:

[image: Segment Selector]

The *Index* and *Table indicator* select a *Segment descriptor* in an straightforward way:

[image: Selection of a Descriptor]

The general *descriptor* format is:

[image: Descriptor]

---

A complete reference can be found in [Intel Manual 3A](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) Chapters 3 - 7.

A short overview can be found in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37556305/5801661) of mine.